# Unit Testing Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql

What are the advantages / disadvantages of the various Unit Testing frameworks for Oracle PL/SQL? For example:

[utPLSQL](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/)

[PL/Unit](http://plunit.com/)

[Pluto](https://code.google.com/p/pluto-test-framework/)

[SqlDeveloper Unit Testing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18464_01/doc.30/e17472/unit_testing.htm)

any other options?

This type of question hasn't been asked in a long time so I'm looking for info that is up-to-date as of 2013.

Comment: For any other option part of the question: I use unit testing part of the http://code.google.com/p/plsql-commons/ (or my own [fork](https://bitbucket.org/janihur/plsql-commons) as I didn't got PL/SQL Commons to work out-of-box).

Comment: I use utPLSQL.  It works for me.  YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

The issue with first three is that they are not being supported by the community anymore.

If I would have to choose I would go with Steven's Feuerstein utPLSQL. His approach is always good.

Pluto - object oriented PL/SQL makes it hard to use. Guy that has written it is pretty smart but somehow the community was not interested and the project died.

Bottom line is: using files to create test cases makes it hard to maintain and share.

Oracle SQL Developer is the best what you can get for free. Easy to use interface plus the most important thing: repository. You can share your work with others and with other projects. Easy in configuration. Test cases can be create on the fly.

There is one more thing. Guys from the Oak table described Oracle SQL Developer unit testing in "Expert PL/SQL Practices". Even if it is sponsored they wouldn't describe it if it was absolute disaster.

My personal opinion.